# Передача файла стандартными сокетами Java

Tags: java, сокет

Доброго времени суток. 
Передаю файл, разбиваю на чанки по 8196 байт и помещаю их в пакет

Пакет

```
public class FileChunk extends BorisPacket 
{
private byte [] chunkarray;

public FileChunk(byte [] chunkarray) 
{
    super(BorisPacket.FILECHUNK);
    this.chunkarray = chunkarray;
}

@Override
public byte[] toByteArray() 
{
    byte [] array = new byte[chunkarray.length + 5];
    array[0] = type;
    array[1] = (byte)(chunkarray.length >> 24);
    array[2] = (byte)(chunkarray.length >> 16);
    array[3] = (byte)(chunkarray.length >> 8);
    array[4] = (byte)(chunkarray.length);
    for(int i=0; i<chunkarray.length; i++)
    {
        array[i+5] = chunkarray[i];
    }

    return array;
}

public byte[] getChunkarray() {
    return chunkarray;
}
```

}

в пакете кроме массива еще protected byte type;

Отправляю так

```
            //отправляем  размер файла  и чанка
            long length = file.length();
            clthread.send(new FilePacket(length, file.getName()));

            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
            //делим файлы на чанки
            int chunk = config.getFilechunksize();
            int count = (int)(length/chunk);
            byte [] filearr = new byte[chunk];

            for(int i=0; i<count; i++) 
            {
                bis.read(filearr);
                clthread.send(new FileChunk(filearr));
            }

            //последний chunk
            int finalchunck = (int)(length % config.getFilechunksize());

            filearr = new byte[finalchunck];
            bis.read(filearr);
            clthread.send(new FileChunk(filearr));
            clthread.send(new BorisPacket(BorisPacket.FILEEND));
        public void send(byte [] array) throws IOException
    {
        this.out.write(array);
        this.out.flush();
    }

    public void send(BorisPacket pack) throws IOException
    {
        this.send(pack.toByteArray());
    }
```

принимаю так

```
socket = serversocket.accept();
worker.Connected(socket); 
in = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
out = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

while((obj = decode.decode(in)) != null)
{
obj = worker.messageReceived(obj);
if(obj != null)
{
    out.write(encode.encode(obj));
    out.flush();
}
}

@Override
public Object messageReceived(Object object) 
{
    BorisPacket bpack = (BorisPacket)object; 
    switch(bpack.getType())
    {   
        case BorisPacket.SAVEFILE:
            this.chunks = 0;
            this.SaveFile(bpack);
            break;

        case BorisPacket.FILECHUNK:
            this.chunks++;
            System.out.println(this.chunks);
            this.saveChunk(bpack);
            break;

        case BorisPacket.FILEEND:
            log.info("received "+this.chunks+" chunks");
            this.SaveTemporyFile(bpack);
            break;
    }
    return null;
}

    //сохранение чанка в поток файла
private void saveChunk(BorisPacket bpack)
{
    try 
    {
        FileChunk chunk = (FileChunk)bpack;
        fos.write(chunk.getChunkarray());
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        log.log(Level.SEVERE, "Exception " + e);
    }
}
```

Проблема в том, что когда я передаю подобным образом файл,
клиент зависает и перестает передавать чанки.
Объясните, что я не так делаю.

Comment: Как минимум то, что с сокетами принято работать в потоках...

Да и после приема чанка клиент должен что-то мявкнуть серверу, что чанк принят. Желательно с использованием чексуммы.

Comment: аааа типа потом только отправлять второй пакет)
благодарю

Comment: @hadoeda, вобщем то если вы используете TCP протокол, то можете не думать о целостности сообщений, протокол за вас все сделает. А если вы будете отправлять клиенту ответы с хеш суммами, то вы просто будете делать двойную работу, передача данных от этого надежнее не станет. Смотрите http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model